How do I include a plugin to my target definition file?
While developing an RCP application, I'm setting up my .target definition file, pointing to the Eclipse 2023-06 update site.  I'm doing this because up until now my .target definition was pointing to my Eclipse installation, and I want to point to the update site.
The problem is that my current installation-based.target has the javax.annotation plugin included, but I can't find a way to include it on the update-site-based.target.
I can see that it is included on the Eclipse 2023-06 release update site, but I can't find a way to include it on my update-site-based.target.
How do I include on my target a plugin that I know is present on the update site, but is not referenced by any selectable feature?
EDIT:  those are the settings I have on my update-site-based.target file. Even if I add all available units from the update sites, the plugin I want is not listed on the contents.
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
    <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.28"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.23.800.v20230523-2142"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.ide" version="4.28.0.I20230605-0440"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="4.28.0.I20230605-0440"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.28.0.v20230605-0440"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.28.0.v20230605-0440"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.28.0.I20230605-0440"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.group" version="2.29.0.v20230315-1321"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient5.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.701.v20230423-0417"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient5.feature.source.feature.group" version="1.1.701.v20230423-0417"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
    <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-06"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature.feature.group" version="3.30.0.v202305230750"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.30.0.v202305221615"/>
</location>


The javax.annotation package is in the jakarta.annotation-api plugin in 2023-06, you should be using Import-Package to reference it rather than Require-Bundle (same with javax.inject). Current versions of Eclipse use jakarta.annotation instead of javax.annotation (again same for inject)

If what greg-449 says does not help to solve your problem, please provide a minimal reproducible example. javax.annotation is deprecated and will no longer supported after December 2025: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/porting/removals.html

Thanks for answering, @greg-449.  It's quite confusing, because on my Eclipse 2023-06 installation, there's no jakarta.annotation-api plugin, but there's a javax.annotation one.

Sure, since the support for Jakarta annotations has been introduced after Eclipse 2023-06. The update site https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-06/ contains the javax.annotation bundle/plugin of version 1.3.5.v20230504-0748. Your question does not show update-site-based.target, so it is unclear what is wrong with it (what you say cannot be reproduced).

Thanks for the answer, @howlger.  I added the inclusions of my .target file on my question.  By the way, the link you posted is related to Eclipse 2023-12, not 2023-06.

My information is from the Eclipse Projects download which I guess may be packaged a bit differently from the full repository. As long as you use Import-Package rather than Require-Bundle it should not matter which plug-in contains the package.

I would recommend to change includeMode="slicer" to includeMode="planner" (see here) and change all versions to version="0.0.0" (which means latest version contained in this repository) in order to make updating easier. Besides these minor things, your target platforms looks fine to me. Are you sure you have set/enable this target platform (double-check the preferences Plug-in Development > Target Platform).

Thanks, @howlger, I'll consider those recommendations.
